# Is it possible to install RAID 10 on Win 8.1 by native means?

Tags: windows-8.1, raid

How can I use RAID 10 (1+0) in Win 8.1? I have 4 identical 4 TB HDs; I aim for an 8 TB space (mirrored).

The Disk Manager does not seem to offer this choice.

Comment: While not technically RAID, the closest native solution, is called Storage Spaces and is a feature in any consumer version of Windows 8+.  Be sure you do research on how many disks can fail in a mirror stripped Storage Space setup.

Comment: you may be better off using an actual raid card instead of using windows. Raid10 is a reasonably simple level, but because Raid0 volumes become completely useless if the set is broken, some additional precaution is indicated, and software raid is less reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not natively supported, but you can actually use Storage Spaces to essentially accomplish this. With Storage Spaces, you can create a pool with a custom number of mirrors and columns to essentially emulate RAID 10 and you can use other advanced features that Storage Spaces provides such as Microsoft's newest filesystem ReFS.

In order to do this, you can use PowerShell and execute some commands.

First, we must open PowerShell by going to start then click on run then type in `powershell` then press enter, thne type in the following commands to create a Storage Pool:

`$stsubsys = (Get-StorageSubsystem)`

`$physd = (Get-PhysicalDisk PhysicalDisk1, PhysicalDisk2, PhysicalDisk3, PhysicalDisk4, PysicalDisk5, PhysicalDisk6)`

`New-StoragePool -FriendlyName MyPool1 -StorageSubsystemFriendlyName $stsubs.FriendlyName -PhysicalDisks $physd`

Then we must create a new Virtual Disk where we specify the number of cloumns (you can specify the resiliency and columns to be whatever you want, but this is an example):

`New-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName NewVDisk -StoragePoolFriendlyName MyPool1 -NumberOfColumns 3 -ResiliencySettingName mirror -UseMaximumSize`

After that, you can simply go into disk manager and then format and assign a drive letter to your Storage Pool Virtual Disk. To do this, go to start, then run, then type in `diskmgmt.msc` then press enter, then find the new disk you created, right click it and create simple volume. Follow the wizard, and then you essentially have software RAID 10 in Windows.

Sources: http://windowsitpro.com/windows/navigating-storage-spaces-and-pools

Comment: So, with 4 Disks PhysicalDisk1...PhysicalDisk4, I would use New-VirtualDisk ... -NumberOfColumns 2 (instead of 3), correct?

Comment: Yup, that is exactly right. It would be 2 stripes (Columns) of 2 drives (a mirror).

Comment: Some remarks and another question: Note, that there is a typo: $stsubs should read $stsubsys. However, I changed my friendly names to "4 x 4 TB" and "RAID 10", resp. - It may also be worth to point out, that the involved disks need to be erased via the disk manager, else New-StoragePool will complain that "one" of the physical disks is not supported. - So, after New-VirtualDisk I get a confirmation, 8 TB available as "RAID 10", only that there is no drive letter and it does not show up in the explorer, how can I access this volume now?

Comment: Allright, to show the new storage space, go to Control Pane, Storage Spaces and Format the new drive.

Answer (score 2):

No, Windows does not natively support software RAID 10.

If you would like to implement advanced storage solutions in Windows 8+ natively, perhaps check out the "[Storage Spaces](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b8/2012/01/05/virtualizing-storage-for-scale-resiliency-and-efficiency/)" feature.

> In a nutshell, Storage Spaces allow:
>
> • Organization of
>   physical disks into storage pools, which can be easily expanded by
>   simply adding disks. These disks can be connected either through USB,
>   SATA (Serial ATA), or SAS (Serial Attached SCSI). A storage pool can
>   be composed of heterogeneous physical disks – different sized physical
>   disks accessible via different storage interconnects.
>
> • Usage of
>   virtual disks (also known as spaces), which behave just like physical
>   disks for all purposes. However, spaces also have powerful new
>   capabilities associated with them such as thin provisioning (more
>   about that later), as well as resiliency to failures of underlying
>   physical media.